# I'm confused about what's recursive, tail recursive, primitive recursive and what's not

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I've written a simple guess the number program and I need to know if there is any kind of recursion involved in it, and what kind it is (primitive/tail) (I'm new to this so please bear with me)

```
module MyProgram where
import System.Random

guessNum :: IO()
guessNum =
do  --gen <- newStdGen
    --let num = randoms gen :: [Int]
    num<-randomRIO(20,100 :: Int)
    putStrLn "Guess the number: "
    input<-getLine
    let guess = (read input :: Int)
    checkGuess guess num


checkGuess:: Int -> Int -> IO()
checkGuess guess num1 |(num1<guess)=
                do  putStr"Too high! Guess again!"
                    input<-getLine
                    let guess = (read input)::Int
                    checkGuess guess num1
                |(num1>guess)=          
                do  putStr"Too low! Guess again!"
                    input<-getLine
                    let guess = (read input)::Int
                    checkGuess guess num1
                |(num1==guess)  =
                do  putStr"Congratulations! You found the number!"
```

Comment: i'm no haskell expert, but recursion is when a function calls itself, and i believe "tail recursion" only occurs when the self-call is the last statement to be executed for the current iteration (i.e., it doesn't need to keep the function on the stack so that it can return and execute more statements)

Comment: I need to know if my function call checkGuess inside checkGuess involves recursion because it does not use any information from the previous occurrences but the num1 passed along in every instance

Comment: Yes, it's recursive. It doesn't have to "use any information from previous occurrences". If it calls itself, it's recursive. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Where did you encounter the term primitive recursion in the context of Haskell? Primitive recursion doesn't really have anything to do with Haskell. Whether a function is tail-recursive or not can have a performance impact in Haskell (and many other functional languages), but whether it's primitive recursive or not, doesn't really matter outside of a TCS context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A function is recursive if it calls itself (not necessarily in every case, but at least in one case). For example:

```
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

The function above is not however tail recursive. In the second equation, `x` and `sum xs` are first computed and the final result is their sum. Since the final result is not a call to the function, it is not tail recursive. To convert this function to tail recursive, we can use the accumulator pattern:

```
sum [] acc = acc
sum (x:xs) acc = sum xs (x + acc)
```

Notice now in the second equation first calculates `xs` and `x + acc` and as a *final step* it calls itself. Tail recursive functions are important because they can be systematically transformed to loops, eliminating the overhead of function calls. Some languages do this optimization, I think this optimization is not necessary in Haskell (see hammar's comment below too).

Your function checkGuess might seem tail recursive but it is not. The `do` syntax is syntactic sugar for using the `>>=` operator.

```
f = do
    x <- g
    h x
```

is transformed to

```
f = g >>= (\x -> h x)
```

therefore, in almost every do notation the last function to be called is `>>=`.

A function is primitive recursive if it can be constructed using the 5 constructs described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition). Addition, multiplication and factorial are examples of primitive recursive functions, while the Ackermann function is not.

This is usually useful in theory of computability but as far as programming goes, one normally does not care (the compiler does not try to do anything about it).

Notes:

- One can say that a group of functions are mutually recursive if the way they call each other has cycles (f calls g, g calls h and h eventually calls f).

Comment: It's worth noting that tail recursion by itself is often not enough to get a constant space loop in Haskell due to laziness. You often also need to use `seq` or a `BangPattern` on the accumulator to ensure that it is evaluated at each step so that it doesn't build up a huge thunk.

Comment: It should be mentioned that "calling itself" doesn't have to be direct, you can have a function `ping` calling `pong`, and `pong` calling `ping`, and it's still considered "recursive".

Comment: @Landei that's called *mutually recursive*.

Comment: @is7s: Mutually recursive code is recursive, hence the name. Recursion means a function is defined in terms of itself. If ping is defined in terms of pong, which in turn is defined in terms ping, then ping is still defined in terms of itself. General tail-**call** optimisation can even execute such functions in constant space if all the calls involved in the cycle are tail-calls.

Answer (score 1):

A function is recursive if it calls itself anywhere in its code. So guessNum isn't (no call to guessNum in guessNum code or in code it calls), and checkGuess is.

Tail recursion is when the recursive call is the last thing the function do... but this is Haskell and tail recursion is a term mainly intended for strict languages where it allows to optimize a recursive function so that it doesn't grow the stack (the current invocation can be straightforwardly replaced by the recursive one since you won't need to do anything after the recursive call returns). So as others have said checkGuess isn't tail recursive or wouldn't be in a strict language... However with lazy semantics, (a >> b) will be evaluated to b in many Monads (IO included) since once a is evaluated (or rather the IO action is done), it can be forgotten and the return of b is the only thing that matter.

In a nutshell, your function checkGuess is recursive, not tail recursive by most formal definitions but those definitions aren't adapted to non-strict languages like Haskell, and checkGuess will most definitely be executed in constant space as if it was tail recursive in a strict language (at least with reasonable implementations of Haskell, such as GHC).

Primitive recursion is a notion defined on N^k -> N functions, I don't think the question makes sense for such a function as checkGuess, not without some doubtful adaptation and looking at a translation of the function in some simpler language (lamda-calculus equivalent) which would means making explicit IO semantics and so on... I would say though that your function doesn't do anything with its Int parameter that wouldn't be possible with a primitive recursive function.

Note that your code repeats itself, maybe the part that should really be abstracted away is :

```
input<-getLine
let guess = (read input :: Int)
checkGuess guess num
```

Answer (score 0):

Tail recursion is when you do nothing after the function calls itself
This is generally done by returning with the next recursion call.

So yours is a tail recursion in  a way, since you do nothing after your checkGuess is called recursively.

Comment: It's not tail recursive.  The last call is to (>>=).  Given certain translations of the IO monad the compiler might turn it into tail recursion.